# Using HTTP between CloudFront and EC2 for HTTPS site

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ec2, https, amazon-cloudfront

Our application is currently running on EC2 instances, requiring HTTPS (and redirecting HTTP to HTTPS). We are now considering serving all requests via CloudFront and enforcing HTTPS through CloudFront. Our thought is that once we do that we would then block HTTP/HTTPS requests not coming from CloudFront and relax the HTTPS requirement. This way all requests to CloudFront would be via HTTPS, but CloudFront would retrieve the data from the EC2 origin via HTTP. This way we would a) reduce some server overhead since the server doesn't have to do the TLS encryption and b) eliminate the need to manage certificates for the EC2 instances.

Are there any security concerns with this or other reasons not to do this?

Comment: If you could limit EC2 inboud/outbound security group to ONLY cloudfront, I think this is fine design. I have seen this in couple of places (unless you have other compliance requirements)

Comment: @Nambari, the only ways to limit it seems to be a) inspecting for Custom Headers (e.g. using URL Rewrite) and forwarding any non-CloudFront requests to CloudFront or b) whitelisting Amazon's IP ranges in a security group (seems like too much of a hack for me). Another solution would be to use ELB instead: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-http-https-elb/

Comment: I would opt for ELB solution if that is within the budget.

Comment: There is one little security implication where, from CloudFront in any AWS account, inbound traffic is allowed to your EC2 instance. Also if you haven't added the CloudFront IPs to your security group. Others can directly access your EC2 instance without SSL

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Why not use a VPN between sites and simply side step all the problems with the web security model, TLS and browsers?

Comment: @jww, this is a single public-facing website.

Comment: Sorry to resurrect this and for the maybe dumb questions, but I'm not sure I understand the concern about the EC2 machine being accessible directly without SSL. I guess IF someone decides to directly use the server (without SSL then), it's kind of their own decision and at their own risk?
What I'm a bit more worried about is that since CloudFront retrieves data from the EC2 machine over plain HTTP, that bit is completely unsecure, isn't it? And that would be very misleading to viewers? Or is Amazon doing some magic to make sure the communication between CloudFront and EC2 was not compromised?

Comment: Does anyone have any info about how secure are Cloudfront to EC2/ELB connections? I'm assuming the connection happen through the AWS internal network, so they are quite secure, but I wonder if one should worry about this connection and also enforce HTTPS there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what we ended up doing:

1. Origin EC2 only allows HTTP (port 80)
2. ELB only allows HTTPS (port 443) and targets the EC2 via HTTP (port 80)
3. EC2 Security Group restricts HTTP access to the ELB's security group
4. Created Route53 DNS entry for origin-blabla.example.com as an alias to the ELB
5. CloudFront distribution redirects HTTP -> HTTPS
6. CloudFront has origin-blabla.example.com as its origin
7. CloudFront origin has custom HTTP header
8. Both CloudFront and ELB have a *.example.com TLS Certificate (I also could have used separate certs for specific domain names)
9. URL Rewrite blocks/redirects all requests that don't have one of the following: a) the above-mentioned custom HTTP header or b) UserAgent that matches ^ELB-HealthChecker$

So now all requests come to CloudFront via HTTPS (if they come as HTTP they are redirected to HTTPS), which connects to ELB via HTTPS, which in turn gets the data from EC2 via HTTP. This cannot be circumvented (unless someone is desperate enough to guess the origin DNS and brute force the custom HTTP header and add it to their browser request - and I'm not sure what they're really gaining by that) so we can rest assured that a) all requests are secure, b) there is only one domain name that can be used to access our system, and c) we don't have to worry about certificates on the server.

Comment: Is there a way doing this without ELB?

Comment: @SabriAziri see Ashan's answer below

Comment: ELB is only needed if there're multiple EC2s

Answer (score 4):

Actually, here in the company where I am working, we have the following scenario.

- EC2 -> ELB -> CF (+ AWS Certificate) = HTTP and HTTPS

  - EC2 always work with 80
  - CF work with both 443 and 80.

It is easy to configure and so far we don't have problems.

Comment: How do you prevent someone from accessing the ELB directly over port 80?

Comment: I'm thinking this could work: CF (HTTP redirects to HTTPS) -> ELB (HTTPS only) -> EC2 (HTTP only). Thoughts?

Comment: When I configure my DNS on Router 53, I just simply add an Alias of the CDN domain distribution. So if someone does a ping, dig or whatever they are gonna get always IPs and never a CNAME. The ELB is just a bridge and nothing else.

Comment: The idea is to try to work only with an Alias. Good for you.

Answer (score 2):

To add additional security you can do the following.

- Having a secret token header sent from CloudFront which is verified at the EC2 instance to serve the request.
- Only allowing the [IP address ranges](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/LocationsOfEdgeServers.html) of CloudFront, in EC2's or ELB's security group for inbound request.